# Python Mastodon API gives same results for following and followers?

Tags: python, mastodon

I am trying to get a list of people I follow, and a lost of people I am followed by, but the functions give the same number?

```
myid = mastodon.account_verify_credentials()["id"]                                                                                                                                                                                        
followed_by = mastodon.account_followers(myid) #Fetch users the given user is followed by.                                                                                                                                                
following = mastodon.account_following(myid) # Fetch users the given user is following.                                                                                                                                                   
binoff = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
print ("followed_by={}, following={}, binoff={}".format(len(followed_by),len(following),len(binoff)))
```

The result is:

> followed_by=40, following=40, binoff=0
> followed_by=40, following=40, binoff=40

Where have I gone wrong

Comment: Could you include `myid` if possible? Also, a sample of `followed_by` or `following` would be nice. Have you tried on another user's id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem. The issue is that there is a rate limit (pagination parameters) on the API. So it only gave me the first 40 accounts. To get the remainder you need to do add the lines:

```
followed_by = mastodon.fetch_remaining(followed_by)   
following = mastodon.fetch_remaining(following)
```

So the API will pull the remaining accounts for you.